# How to I check if email exist in user table with codeinighter and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want users to enter their email click a button and then check to see if the email is already in the database
this is what i tried so far with no success

**model**

```
public function email_exists($email) {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
}
```

**Controller**

```
 function email_exists(){
          $this->load->model('main_model');
          $email = $this->input->post('email');
          $exists = $this->main_model->email_exists($email);
          $count = count($exists);
          echo $count;  
           if (empty($count)) {
                return true;
          } else {
               return false;
         } 
 }
```

**View**
Im adding the ajax code in the view im not sure if this is right

```
<input id="about-email" type="email">
<div id="about-you" >enter</div>
<script>
       var email = $("#about-email").val();
       $('#about-you').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/my_controller_name/email_exists",
                    data:{ email:email},
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        if (response == true) {
                            $('#msg').html('<span>email exists</span>');
                        } else  {
                            $('#msg').html('<span>Value does not exist</span>');
                        }  
                    }
                });
    });
</script>
```

The ajax code above breaks all my javascript for that page I'm also making a another ajax call on the same page so I don't know if it possible to make 2 ajax calls on one page.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i'm not getting an error. but all the js items are broken on the view page

Comment: thats what you need to post....what do you mean by broken ?

Comment: Like i have js to switch divs and thats not working

Comment: What's the console output? is there any error? Also, the response want have `true` as a value.

Comment: there is no console output.

Comment: In the page source what's the `url` assgined value looks like? is it right? @Tsea

Comment: There should be some error in your console log,did you check it?

Comment: I'm now getting a 404 not found the url is not returning correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax should be like this:

```
    <script>
       var email = $("#about-email").val();
       var url = <?= base_url("my_controller_name/email_exists") ?>
       $('#about-you').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {email: email},
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        if (response) {
                            $('#msg').html('<span>email exists</span>');
                        } else  {
                            $('#msg').html('<span>Value does not exist</span>');
                        }  
                    }
                });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
```

And in your controller:

```
    function email_exists(){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->load->model('main_model');
        $exists = $this->main_model->email_exists($email);
        $exists = (count($exists) > 0)? true : false;
        echo json_encode($exists);   
    }
```

Comment: the url is breaking base_url is not working and when i hard code the url it repeats itself like 'url.com/index.php/url.com/index.php/my_controller_name/email_exists'

Comment: Try: `<?= base_url('/my_controller_name/email_exists');?>`

Comment: In your page source, what is the value of `url` in the ajax request?

Comment: Its just blank and cuts off at url it looks like    type:"get",   url: "   then the page just stops

Comment: Try to output the `<?= base_url('/my_controller_name/email_exists');?>` in a blank page, see if there's any error there!

Comment: Its breaking the page. do i need to make a view for "email_exists" because im trying to access it in a view called 'choose' or do i add it to the 'choose' view

Comment: No you don't have to make a view for it. How it's breaking the page, I just want you to write a new method in the controller and try to call it by putting the right link in the address bar in your browser.

Comment: The new method has a single line: `echo base_url('/my_controller_name/email_exists/ANY_THING');` @Tsea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124076/discussion-between-tsea-and-mazux).